# vba shell java call errors

Tags: java, ms-access, vba, windows-shell

In an MS Access public function, I run a java xslt module using a shell call:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmd = "java -jar D:\saxon9he.jar -s:D:\input.xml -xsl:D:\transf.xslt -o:D:\output.xml"
Set objExecObject = shell.Exec(cmd)
```

I caught the following error:

[image: VBA java call error]

As exactly the same worked fine in another MS Access instance, I assume I have to refer to an environment variable somewhere (one of these is `JAVA_HOME` which has been set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_16\bin`).
But where in MS Access can I set that reference?
Or is this error caused by something else?
Might there for instance be trouble with MS Access / VBA accessing the environment variable `PATH` in `USER` and/or `SYSTEM`? In my setup, it's the user environment paramater `PATH` that holds the information on the location of java.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added stuff to the command to be executed as follows:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim JavaHome As String
JavaHome = shell.Environment("USER")("JAVA_HOME") & "\"
cmd = JavaHome & "java -jar D:\saxon9he.jar -s:D:\input.xml -xsl:D:\transf.xslt -o:D:\output.xml"
Set objExecObject = shell.Exec(cmd)
```

This works fine, as I now supply the path to java.exe myself.

But I still wonder, why all of a sudden MSA/VBA could not apply the `PATH` parameter from user environment (which includes ;%JAVA_HOME%;) any more...

I will create another thread for that question...