# How to use java method in VBA

Tags: java, vba, excel

The question is how to return a string from java method in VBA.
For example I have a code in java:

```
package someclass;

public class SomeClass {

    public static String someMethod(String s){
        return "this is some string: "+s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(someMethod("Hello world!"));
    } 

}
```

Now the question is how to call someMethod in VBA?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, do you want to convert this java code to VBA?

Comment: The only way I see is you make a DLL (using C++, VB.NET or similar others) that consumes your Java functions, then add a reference to that DLL to your VBA project and call them via the DLL which serves as bridge. As far as I know, there's no direct bridge between VBA and Java. You might run a method from VBA of your JAR file using a shell command, but I don't think you can return the function in VBA though.

Comment: This is just example. Off course there is no sense to use particular example in real VBA. I had encryptor and decryptor methods in java, so I want to use this methods in VBA.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343769/microsoft-excel-macro-to-run-java-program

Comment: I tried to use ikmvc (http://weblog.ikvm.net/2015/08/26/IKVMNET81ReleaseCandidate0.aspx) to convert jar to dll, but when I registered it with regsvr32 I got the error message: The module "<mypath>\mydll.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Comment: Thanks to @Slai, the way proposed by mschwehl in link stackoverflow.com/questions/11343769/ does work. I just need to do 
 in java: System.out.print()   and so I can get it in VBA.

Comment: So using    \n Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    'run command'
    Dim oExec As Object
    Dim oOutput As Object
    Set oExec = oShell.exec(sCmd)
    Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1):

Use Jinx, the Excel Java Add-In, to call your Java method as an Excel macro.

See https://exceljava.com for details.

All you would need to do in your example is to add the @ExcelMacro annotation to your method to make it callable from Excel as a macro.

```
package someclass;

import com.exceljava.jinx.ExcelMacro;

public class SomeClass {

    @ExcelMacro
    public static String someMethod(String s){
        return "this is some string: "+s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(someMethod("Hello world!"));
    } 

}
```

See https://exceljava.com/docs/macros.html for more details about writing Excel macros in Java using Jinx.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mschwehl answer (i.e. possible solution)  here:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/11343769/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343769/)

Comment: Close as duplicate if it is the same.. please dont copy paste entire answer

Comment: Hi @SurajRao, Sorry I didn't know It's forbidden.